# Mark Cookies as Secured in Android Webview

Tags: android, cookies

I need to mark the cookies as secured when I use them with CookieManager in Android WebView.
How can I do that?

Comment: This needs a lot more information. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(DOMAIN_NAME+COOKIE_PATH);
        BasicCookieStore cookieJar = new BasicCookieStore();
        if (!cookie.equals("")) {
            String[] cookies = cookie.split(";");
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                String[] nvp = cookies[i].split("=");
                BasicClientCookie c = new BasicClientCookie(nvp[0], nvp[1]);
                c.setDomain(DOMAIN_NAME);
                c.setPath(COOKIE_PATH);
                c.setSecure(true);
                cookieJar.addCookie(c);
            }
        }
```